# How to save Obj-C block in a C struct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, struct, completionhandler

I want to call a C function from my ObjC. I am passing a C function reference (defined in ObjC) in a C struct so that C can call that function. I also want to pass the reference to a completion-block to C, so that when I get a callback, I can call that completion-block. But I do not know how to implement that. I get different errors based on the different typecasting I tried.

```
//Abc.m

void myCallback(MyData *data) 
{
  //I get the control here!
  //((__bridge void *)(data->completionBlock))([NSString stringWithCString:data->json]); //how to call the completion block?
}

- (void)myMethod:(NSString)input
             completion:(void (^)(NSString * _Nullable response))completionBlock 
{
    MyData *data = malloc(sizeof(MyData));
    data->myCallback = myCallback;
    data->completionBlock = (__bridge void *)(completionBlock);//is this correct?
    cFunction(data);
}


//Xyz.c

typedef struct
{
  char *json;
  void (*myCallback)(void *response);
  void *completionBlock;
} MyData;

void cFunction(MyData *data)
{
  data->json = "some response";
  (data->myCallback)(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues to consider:

1. Casting: You need to cast to appropriate types, e.g. your commented out `(__bridge void *)(data->completionBlock)` doesn't give you back a block type so the compiler will reject the call.
2. Ownership: Blocks are just objects in Objective-C and are managed by ARC for you. In C blocks are manually managed. You must ensure that the block you pass into your C structure will not be released by ARC, and having used it you must ensure that it is freed.

Following your code design let's first define a type to make things easier:

```
typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(NSString * _Nullable response);
```

With that your `myMethod` function starts as before:

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSString*)input
      completion:(CompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
   MyData *data = malloc(sizeof(MyData));
   data->myCallback = myCallback;
```

Now you must store your block into your struct while making sure ARC does not release it on the Objective-C side. To do that you use `__bridge_retain` which returns a retained reference to the block, your code will be responsible for balancing that retain. That can either be done in your C code or you can transfer the ownership back to ARC and let it take care of it. So the remainder of `myMethod` is:

```
   data->completionBlock = (__bridge_retained void *)(completionBlock);
   cFunction(data);
}
```

Now your `cFunction` just calls your `myCallBack` function so in this case there is no need to change anything there.

Now to your `myCallBack`, first we fix the type mismatch and define it to take a `void *` and then recover the `MyData *`:

```
void myCallback(void *response)
{
   MyData *data = response;
```

Now we need to recover the block. We could just cast it to the block type, but that would leave us with the job of freeing it (using `Block_release()`) after we've used it; however we can use `__bridge_transfer` to hand back ownership to ARC so it will manage it:

```
   CompletionBlock completionBlock = (__bridge_transfer CompletionBlock)data->completionBlock;
```

Now we get the string out and convert it to an `NSString`:

```
   NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:data->json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And then free the malloc'ed wrapper:

```
   free(data);
```

Finally we call the block:

```
   completionBlock(result);
}
```

The above followed your design, but there is no need to have your C function call another C function in your Objective-C file to call the block - blocks are a C language feature and supported in `.c` files by Clang. You can just cast `data->completionBlock` to the block type, invoke it, and then use `Block_release()` to free the block.

Further as blocks are C types you can type the struct field `completionBlock` with a block type and remove a lot of casts (but those cases cost nothing at runtime).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`__bridge` means to use c style pointer, its behaviour like `assign` or `__unsafe_unretained`.

You use it mean `data->completionBlock` just point to `completionBlock` without retain, so you may crash when `completionBlock` has been released.

If you wanna access block or objective-c object in struct with ARC, you have to declare these with `__unsafe_unretained` and manager their life by yourself.

```
typedef struct {
char *json;
__unsafe_unretained NSString *name;
__unsafe_unretained CompletionBlock block;
} SampleStruct;
```

Comment: As you can see, the struct is defined in C; so CompletionBlock is Unknown type name.

Comment: Completion is a block declaration like `typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(void);` If you wanna access block in pure c file, just declare with `void *`, but you need to manager life by yourself.

Comment: You can see that I am already using void *. But getting bad access error when I call it from myCallback method

Comment: you have to manager `completeBlock` life by yourself. It's obvious that finish method '-myMethod:completion:', completeBlock has been released.